# Is it possible to configure IIS to always redirect to html inside folder based on folder name?

Tags: html, iis

I'm very new to IIS, so I'm not sure what I'm trying to ask.  I have for each day about 5-10 static html pages contained in a folder, and the folder names are just the date, and I'd like for users to be directed to the most recent folder whenever they enter the main url.  Any of the html pages inside the folder will do.

For example, if the url is "mysite.com", I'd like "mysite.come" to send them to "mysite.com/2015-01-02/main.html" for today, and tomorrow after I build the html pages for them to be sent to "mysite.com/2015-01-03/main.html".

Does that make sense?  Is that possible?  Thanks!

Comment: if they go to mysite.come and you don't have that domain in DNS, it can go somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, but not with plain iis. You need some programming to do the redirecting. Like asp.net.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I managed to do it, but not using IIS features directly.  I created a default.html page that had a redirect, and plan to update the default.html page in the same way I update the directory each day.  Thank you for your comment, it was helpful.